# R: combination of multivariate normal and exponential distribution

Tags: r, correlation, normal-distribution, multivariate-testing, exponential-distribution

I have a set of 7 parameters with high correlation and I need to be able to extract randomly generated sets. However, my variables do not all follow a multivariate normal distribution. I've plotted the distribution of the parameters below where you can see that the last 2 parameters seem to follow an exponential and a uniform distribution respectively. How can I generate random sets? [image: distrib]

Comment: sounds like a question to cross-validated

Comment: you might want to check out copulas, e.g. the `copula` package on CRAN, http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i04/paper , http://www.r-bloggers.com/copulas-made-easy/ ...